# Elastic search index that is deleted daily - will this broke performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

I got data set scrapped from web pages.
I'm saving it in ES index
I decided to scrape data and recreate index each day.

#### Question

Will this broke performance of elastic search?
Is elastic search tuning data somehow over time to make access quicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Elasticsearch has it own caches plus OS caches so using an index can improve performance but it takes a short time to warm them up usually.